# How do I create a SQL Server project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am creating SQL Server database (not server) project for our existing database using VS2015 and SSDT (the latest version I think). I ran into a compile error saying :

> Error     SQL71501: User: [xxxxx] has an unresolved reference to Login
>   [xxxxxx].

I came across [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f8226fe-b791-4344-8735-3d38307e8664/error-1-sql03006-user-x-has-an-unresolved-reference-to-login-x?forum=vstsdb) post (the answer by Demetri M), that suggests to create a server project and have a current project reference that, but I do not see an option to create SQL Server SERVER (not Database) project in VS2015.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47(v=vs.90).aspx) documentation from MSDN didn't help either.Is this something that is no longer valid?

Comment: Things changed a little between versions, but as the answers below note, you're almost always better off not adding logins/users to your project - especially when they differ between environments. If they are the same everywhere, you can import users/logins into the current project and reference them that way. In general, I've found that handling the users and logins elsewhere is the best solution at this time. I blogged on one other possibility here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

Comment: @PeterSchott - Thanks for pointing out the blog. By the way, is there an easier way to remove the imported login/users/permission without having to redo everything again?

Comment: Besides just deleting their files from the project? That should be all you need to do, though if you use DB Roles for permissions, I might leave those.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble, but my users are the same across every deployment target, so managing them in the db project seems the right way to do it. However, as with the OP, I can't find a "SQL Server Project" type - was this removed?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a "create login" for the user.

If you don't want to manage users in Ssdt (most don't) then add a dummy login and use my filter when you deploy to not deploy logins:

Ed

Answer (score 2):

Do not import users and logins. When you import the database, you have the option to specify that. Also make sure that when you publish - you do not drop the users and roles.